# Attempt to read property "id" on null

Tags: null

Need Support
When user going to subscribe, follow link: https://royaleg.co/account/packages/3/subscribe

test user here:
https://royaleg.co/login

user: test           pass: 123456

I created admin account for you: https://royaleg.co/admin

login: helper         pass: 123456

you can find the Currencies setting @ left side->Real Estate->Setting
"Don't worry about data, it's not super admin"

```html
/home/ssmkngbx/domains/royaleg.co/public_html/platform/plugins/real-estate/src/Providers/HookServiceProvider.php
                        app(TransactionInterface::class)->createOrUpdate([
                            'user_id' => 0,
                            'account_id' => $payment->customer_id,
                            'credits' => $package->number_of_listings,
                            'payment_id' => $payment ? $payment->id : null,
                        ]);
                    }
                }, 123, 2);
            }
 
            if (defined('PAYMENT_FILTER_PAYMENT_DATA')) {
                add_filter(PAYMENT_FILTER_PAYMENT_DATA, function (array $data, Request $request) {
                    $orderIds = [session('subscribed_packaged_id')];
 
                    $package = $this->app->make(PackageInterface::class)
                        ->findById(Arr::first($orderIds));
 
                    $products = [
                        [
                          'id' => $package->id,
                            'name' => $package->name,
                            'price' => $package->price,
                            'price_per_order' => $package->price,
                            'qty' => 1,
                        ],
                    ];
 
                    $account = auth('account')->user();
 
                    $address = [
                        'name' => $account->name,
                        'email' => $account->email,
                        'phone' => $account->phone,
                        'country' => null,
                        'state' => null,
                        'city' => null,
                        'address' => null,
                        'zip' => null,
                    ];
 
Arguments
"Attempt to read property "id" on null"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTs1j.png)

Comment: Hi, pls try to post your code using the *Code Sample* functionality instead of posting a link to a picture. Also pls give more context on what are you doing and what is your problem. From the image, the only thing I can tell you is that the variable ```package``` is null for this execution. And is probably null because it doesn't find anything.

Comment: I have made edits to make it more clear